# Neo4j: Cypher: How to remove labels by pattern?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have a Neo4j database where each node has labels starting with underscore.

For example, `(:User,_User), (:Store,:_Store)` etc.

These underscore labels were generated by Spring Data Neo4j and now I want to get rid of them (`call db.schema()` returns them as a separate node in the schema).

Goal to get only `(:User), (:Store)`.

Is there any way to do that with some query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the labels that start with underscores (e.g. `_User`) from those nodes and replace them with values without the undescore then calls to `db.schema()` should no longer return the values.

You could do something like this...

```
MATCH (n:_User)
SET n:User 
REMOVE n:_User
```

Updated answer based on feedback. You could do something like this using APOC.

```
// get all labels that start with underscore
CALL db.labels()
YIELD label AS old_label
WHERE old_label STARTS WITH '_'
WITH old_label, substring(old_label, 1, length(old_label)) AS new_label

// match the nodes for one of the underscore labels
MATCH (n)
WHERE old_label IN labels(n)
WITH old_label, new_label, collect(n) AS relabel_nodes

// call removeLabels with the list of nodes and list od labels to remove
CALL apoc.create.removeLabels(relabel_nodes, [old_label])
YIELD node AS removed_label_node

// call addLabels with the new label to add
WITH removed_label_node, new_label
CALL apoc.create.addLabels(removed_label_node, [new_label])
YIELD node AS added_label_node
RETURN added_label_node
```

Comment: Dave, I have around 160 unique labels with underscore so I am looking to do this in one shot with some query instead of manually removing every label with underscore.

Comment: got it. Added an update that I think will get you started.

Comment: in the end, I went manually because I forgot to mention that I am on Neo4j 2.3.5, there is no APOC. Marking this answer as correct because version is not mentioned and it will help somebody in the future. Thanks